# Can't install gem: Failed to build gem native extension while trying to install Watir

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I am trying to install Watir, but when I try to run `sudo gem install watir` I get this error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170429-29912-10tswho.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

How can I install Watir?

Answer (score 1):

I had to run a few commands to get it to work.

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Then, while looking back at the documentation, I realized I also had to install `selenium-webdriver`

`sudo gem install selenium-webdriver`

You might also have to run the following command before installing `selenium-webdriver`

`sudo gem update --system`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing :

```
gem install test-kitchen
```

My fix was:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then the installation completed smoothly

Done installing documentation for ffi, gssapi, httpclient, rubyntlm, little-plugger, multi_json, logging, nori, builder, gyoku, erubis, winrm, rubyzip, winrm-fs, winrm-elevated, test-kitchen after 24 seconds
16 gems installed